# How to recursively adding a line of code for plot text with given a given condition

Tags: python, class, matplotlib

So, from this graph below, I find discrete points and their indexes. When we draw a final figure, the figure should have the information of when is the exact time that discontinuity happened and vertical line at the discontinuity should be added. In order to do that, I had to add "plt.axvline" and "plt.text" together as a pair.

[image: Graph with break points]

I wrote out the code like this here:

However, whenever new index comes, it's very inconvenient to add two lines of code manually, and what if 100 discontinuities manifested than it's almost nearly impossible to add them.

I am thinking of object oriented method for this like "class" but I have no idea where to start..

Any idea of how to recursively adding it with knowing length of indexes?

```
if len(idx) == 1 :     
    plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
    plt.axvline(x=idx[0], color = 'r')
    plt.text(idx[0],.13, '{}'.format(send_time[idx[0]-1]))
    plt.title(var)
    plt.scatter(x, result, alpha = alp)
    plt.savefig("XXX.png")
    plt.close()
elif len(idx) == 2:
    plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
    plt.axvline(x=idx[0], color = 'r')
    plt.text(idx[0],.10, '{}\n{}'.format(send_time[idx[0]], time1[idx[0]]))
    plt.axvline(x=idx[1], color = 'b')
    plt.text(idx[1],.10, '{}'.format(send_time[idx[1]-1]))
    plt.title(var)
    plt.scatter(x, result, alpha = alp)
    plt.savefig("XXX.png")
    plt.close()
elif len(idx) == 3:
    plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
    plt.axvline(x=idx[0], color = 'r')
    plt.text(idx[0],.13, '{}\n{}'.format(send_time[idx[0]],time1[idx[0]]))
    plt.axvline(x=idx[1], color = 'b')
    plt.text(idx[1],.12, '{}\n{}'.format(send_time[idx[1]],time1[idx[1]]))
    plt.axvline(x=idx[2], color = 'y')
    plt.text(idx[2],.11, '{}'.format(send_time[idx[2]-1]))
    plt.title(var)
    plt.scatter(x, result, alpha = alp)
    plt.savefig("XXX.png")
    plt.close()
```

Comment: is the different colour important for each axvline? Otherwise, a simple for-loop over idx could do the job

Comment: @jrmylow Would you please give me a short example of doing it with for loop ? I think I could use the same color for that.

Comment: what's the significance of send_time and time1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's better to loop over a collection directly `for item in collection` rather than using indices.

```py
plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
for num in idx:
    plt.axvline(num, color = 'r')
    plt.text(num, .13, '{}'.format(send_time[num-1]))
plt.title(var)
plt.scatter(x, result, alpha = alp)
plt.savefig("XXX.png")
plt.close()
```